# Setting conditional variables in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, multiarch

I'm trying to create a multi-architecture docker image via buildkit, using the [predefined `TARGETARCH` arg](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#automatic-platform-args-in-the-global-scope) variable.

What I want to do is - I think - something like bash variable indirection, but I understand that's not supported and I'm struggling to come up with an alternative.

Here's what I've got:

```
FROM alpine:latest

# Buildkit should populate this on build with e.g. "arm64" or "amd64"
ARG TARGETARCH

# Set some temp variables via ARG... :/
ARG DOWNLOAD_amd64="x86_64"
ARG DOWNLOAD_arm64="aarch64"

ARG DOWNLOAD_URL="https://download.url/path/to/toolkit-${DOWNLOAD_amd64}"

# DOWNLOAD_URL must also be set in container as ENV var.
ENV DOWNLOAD_URL $DOWNLOAD_URL

RUN echo "Installing Toolkit" && \
    curl -sSL ${DOWNLOAD_URL} -o /tmp/toolkit-${DOWNLOAD_amd64}
```

... which is a bit pseudo-code but hopefully illustrates what I'm trying to do: I want the value of either `$DOWNLOAD_amd64` or `$DOWNLOAD_arm64` dropped into `$DOWNLOAD_URL`, depending on what `$TARGETARCH` is set to.

This is probably a long-solved issue but either I'm googling the wrong stuff or just not getting it.

Comment: Should this dockerfile only work for `arm64` and `amd64`?

Comment: That's the only requirement at the moment, although the flexibility to add more would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, was not complete. Here a full working solution:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG TARGETARCH

ARG DOWNLOAD_amd64="x86_64"
ARG DOWNLOAD_arm64="aarch64"
WORKDIR /tmp
ARG DOWNLOAD_URL_BASE="https://download.url/path/to/toolkit-"
RUN touch .env; \
    if [ "$TARGETARCH" = "arm64" ]; then \
    export DOWNLOAD_URL=$(echo $DOWNLOAD_URL_BASE$DOWNLOAD_arm64) ; \
    elif [ "$TARGETARCH" = "amd64" ]; then \
    export DOWNLOAD_URL=$(echo $DOWNLOAD_URL_BASE$DOWNLOAD_amd64) ; \
    else \
    export DOWNLOAD_URL="" ; \
    fi; \
    echo DOWNLOAD_URL=$DOWNLOAD_URL > .env; \
    curl ... #ENVS JUST VALID IN THIS RUN!
 
COPY ./entrypoint.sh ./entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

ENV_FILE=/tmp/.env
if [ -f "$ENV_FILE" ]; then
    echo "export " $(grep -v '^#' $ENV_FILE | xargs -d '\n') >> /etc/bash.bashrc
    rm $ENV_FILE
fi

trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait
```

Test:

```
# bash
root@da1dd15acb64:/tmp# echo $DOWNLOAD_URL
https://download.url/path/to/toolkit-aarch64
```

### Now for Alpine:

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.13
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
```

Entrypoint.sh

```
ENV_FILE=/tmp/.env
if [ -f "$ENV_FILE" ]; then
    echo "export " $(grep -v '^#' $ENV_FILE) >> /etc/profile.d/environ.sh
    rm $ENV_FILE
fi
```

Alpine does not accept `xargs -d`. But not that interesting here due to the fact URL does not contain any blank..

Testing:
Alpine just uses that for login shells.. so:

```
docker exec -it containername sh --login
echo $DOWNLOAD_URL
```

Comment: the exported `DOWNLOAD_URL` will not propagate to subsequent `RUN` instructions.

Comment: Yeah, this could be used to do the installation step, i.e. wrap it around the `curl` command, but how do I set $DOWNLOAD_URL as an ENV var in the built image?

Comment: @Wintermute: I would create some .env file via the same RUN statement and load that in entrypoint.

Comment: Once you've run `curl` in the image, you can unpack it to a known architecture-independent path (`/opt/toolkit` or `/usr/local`) at which point you shouldn't need to know the original URL any more.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the replies everyone. I guess the above is the most elegant way available right now, so that's what I'll go with :)

Comment: you could have just used
`DOWNLOAD_URL=${DOWNLOAD_URL_BASE}$(uname -m)`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and landed here for ideas to solve it. In the end, I used `uname -p`

```
curl -sSL https://download.url/path/to/toolkit-$(uname -p) -o /tmp/toolkit-${TARGETARCH}
```